# Имитация множественного наследования с переопределением методов

Tags: наследование, typescript, множественное-наследование, mixins, прототипное-наследование

В [прошлый раз](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/473837/178988) я узнал, как сделать, чтобы тайпскрипт увидел методы, копируемые в прототип класса из другого места. Все способы сводились к объявлению типов полей:

[Фиддл](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('someMethod%20from%20First')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log('Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ASecond.prototype.doSmth%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log('doSmth%20from%20Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Both%20extends%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('constructor%20of%20Both')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Second.call(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20doSmth%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20Second.prototype)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Both.prototype%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20Second.prototype%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Final%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doIt()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.someMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.doSmth()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Both.prototype.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Final.prototype.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

```
class First {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('someMethod from First');
  }
}

function Second() {
  console.log('Second');
}

Second.prototype.doSmth = function () { 
  console.log('doSmth from Second');
}

class Both extends First {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor of Both');
    super();
    Second.call(this);
  }

  doSmth: () => void
}

for (let key in Second.prototype) {
  Both.prototype[key] = Second.prototype[key];
}

class Final extends Both {
  doIt() {
    this.someMethod();
    this.doSmth();
    Both.prototype.doSmth(); // ok
    Final.prototype.doSmth(); // ok
  }
}
```

Однако, сейчас понадобилось в одном из наследников переопределить такой метод:

```
class OtherFinal extends Both {
    doSmth() { // Здесь ошибка
        console.log('doSmth from OtherFinal');
    }
}
```

> Class 'Both' defines instance member property 'doSmth', but class 'OtherFinal' defines it as instance member function.

Собственно, сообщение вполне логичное.
Но как ещё можно заставить typescript увидеть метод, который в нём явно не прописан?

Все способы приводят к той же проблеме (ссылки ведут на соответствующие фиддлы):
[`doSmth: () => void`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('someMethod%20from%20First')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log('Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ASecond.prototype.doSmth%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log('doSmth%20from%20Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Both%20extends%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('constructor%20of%20Both')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Second.call(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20doSmth%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20Second.prototype)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Both.prototype%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20Second.prototype%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Final%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doIt()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.someMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.doSmth()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Both.prototype.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Final.prototype.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20OtherFinal%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%09doSmth()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log('doSmth%20from%20OtherFinal')%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A), [`doSmth: typeof Second.prototype.doSmth;`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('someMethod%20from%20First')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log('Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ASecond.prototype.doSmth%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log('doSmth%20from%20Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Both%20extends%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('constructor%20of%20Both')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Second.call(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20doSmth%3A%20typeof%20Second.prototype.doSmth%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20Second.prototype)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Both.prototype%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20Second.prototype%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Final%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doIt()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.someMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.doSmth()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Both.prototype.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Final.prototype.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20OtherFinal%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%09doSmth()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log('doSmth%20from%20OtherFinal')%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Ясно, что можно объявить функцию 
[`doSmth() {}`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('someMethod%20from%20First')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log('Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ASecond.prototype.doSmth%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log('doSmth%20from%20Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Both%20extends%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('constructor%20of%20Both')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Second.call(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20doSmth()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20Second.prototype)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Both.prototype%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20Second.prototype%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Final%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doIt()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.someMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.doSmth()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Both.prototype.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Final.prototype.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20OtherFinal%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%09doSmth()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log('doSmth%20from%20OtherFinal')%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A), но в таком случае в скомпилированный код попадает мусор, так что так делать не хотелось бы.

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/35658109/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35658109/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Нужно для `Second` объявить `interface`.
2. `Both` следует объявить как интерфейс, наследующийся от `First` и `Second`.
3. Реализовать `Both` как функцию-конструктор с ручной реализацией наследования.
   Сохранить в переменную `Both`, объявленную как конструктор, возвращающий `Both`.
   Для приведения использовать `as any`.

Вот полный код:

```
class First {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('someMethod from First');
  }
}

interface Second {
  constructor(): Second;
  doSmth(): void;
}

function Second() {
  console.log('Second');
}

Second.prototype.doSmth = function () { 
  console.log('doSmth from Second');
}

interface Both extends First, Second {
  constructor(): Both;
  doBoth(): void;
}

var Both: { new (): Both } = function () {
  console.log('constructor of Both');
  First.call(this);
  Second.call(this);
} as any;

Both.prototype = Object.create(First.prototype);

Both.prototype.doBoth = function () {
  this.someMethod(); // ok
  this.doSmth(); // ok
}

for (let key in Second.prototype) {
  Both.prototype[key] = Second.prototype[key];
}

class Final extends Both {
  doIt() {
    this.someMethod();
    this.doSmth();
    Both.prototype.doSmth(); // ok
    Final.prototype.doSmth(); // ok
  }
}

class OtherFinal extends Both {
  doSmth() { // ok
    console.log('doSmth from OtherFinal');
  }
}
```

PS: Решение найдено при поиске [ответа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630410/178988) на другой вопрос.